# max() function in R returned a value that did not equal to itself

Tags: r

I used max(d[,2:3]) to extract the largest number of two columns of a data frame, but I got really weird value:

```
> head(D)
          CD41 label clusterID
1 0.0011454440     7         5
2 1.0996334553    10         4
3 0.0011956851     9        12
4 0.0992929861    13        12
5 0.0008555306     7         5
6 0.0001552506     7         5
> d=head(D)
> max(d[,2:3])
[1] 13
> 1:max(d[,2:3])
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
> max(d[,2:3])
[1] 13
> max(d[,2:3])==13
[1] FALSE
> max(d[,2:3])==12
[1] FALSE
> is.numeric(max(d[,2:3]))
[1] TRUE
```

How could a numeric "13" not equal to 13? I'm really puzzled. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you post the `dput(d)`

Comment: Please post `str(d)` and we can see the datatypes of cols 2,3 to see if they're numeric, int or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it didn't work may be due to the floating point.  It may be that the values having some precision.

```
round(max(d[,2:3]))==13
```

---

Note that the OP subset only the `head` of the dataset.  The columns could be `numeric` class even though it is appearing as `integer` class in the `head`.  This means that if the value is `13.000000001` or `12.9999999` it won't be equal to 13.

---

By copying the data, it gives the correct output

```
max(d[,2:3])==13
#[1] TRUE
```

#### data

```
d <- structure(list(CD41 = c(0.001145444, 1.0996334553, 0.0011956851, 
0.0992929861, 0.0008555306, 0.0001552506), label = c(7L, 10L, 
9L, 13L, 7L, 7L), clusterID = c(5L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 5L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried m=max(as.matrix(d[,2:3])), but 1:m still returned 1 to 12

Comment: @weichensong. Do you see `d$label[4] - 13` not equal to 0

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance! Now it turned out to be the problem of floating points. In earlier steps of definition of data frame D, i added a ceiling() step and it worked well now.